# Quotename function in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

The question I have is

Why use:

```
QUOTENAME ('simple string', '''');
```

Instead of:

```
QUOTENAME ('simple string', ' ' ');
```

if I want to use single quotation as the delimiter?  I assume it has to do with escaping, but can't find any detailed explanation about this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two single-quotes together indicate a zero-length string.

Three single-quotes together indicate an escaped single quote; i.e. ''' becomes '

Four single-quotes together indicate an escaped single quote followed by another single quote, which is translated into a quotated single quote, similar to what you desire.  I know, it's confusing.  Try writing nested dynamic SQL, and you'll pretty quickly find strings with 7, 8, or more single quotes in a row.

Consider the output of the following three statements:

```
SELECT '[' + '' + ']'
SELECT '[' + '''' + ']'
SELECT '[' + '''-''' + ']'
```

```
[]

[']

['-']
```

Typical usage of `QUOTENAME()` is to protect against SQL Injection when concatenating T-SQL strings, by escaping text that is provided by a user.  For instance:

```
DECLARE @MyInput VARCHAR(50);
SET @MyInput = 'some table name';
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@MyInput) + ';';
PRINT (@cmd);
```

will output `SELECT * FROM [some table name];`.

If you don't use the `QUOTENAME()` function:

```
DECLARE @MyInput VARCHAR(50);
SET @MyInput = 'some table name';
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @MyInput + ';';
PRINT (@cmd);
```

You get `SELECT * FROM some table name;` which is not valid T-SQL because of the spaces in `some table name`.

Here comes little bobby tables:

[image]

You can see the effect of quotename in the following code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Students') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Students;
CREATE TABLE #Students
(
    StudentName VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO #Students (StudentName) VALUES ('Max');

SELECT *
FROM #Students;

    DECLARE @MyInput VARCHAR(50);
    SET @MyInput = 'Robert'';DROP TABLE #Students--';
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
    SET @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM #Students WHERE StudentName = ''' + QUOTENAME(@MyInput, '''') + ''';';
    PRINT (@cmd);
    EXEC (@cmd);

SELECT *
FROM #Students;

GO

    DECLARE @MyInput VARCHAR(50);
    SET @MyInput = 'Robert'';DROP TABLE #Students--';
    DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
    SET @cmd = 'SELECT * FROM #Students WHERE StudentName = ''' + @MyInput + ''';';
    PRINT (@cmd);
    EXEC (@cmd);

SELECT *
FROM #Students;
```

The output:

[image]

With the `QUOTENAME()` function, we do get an error message, but without the function, we allow our user to drop the `#Students` table.

Note, I'm using *4 single quotes* in my `QUOTENAME()` function, since that is actually interpreted as one single quote, and used to wrap the text provided to the function, thereby making that text "safe".

Erland Sommarskog has an excellent piece on dynamic SQL at http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html - this is well worth reading (and understanding!) if you are considering doing dynamic SQL.

Comment: Thanks, I will need quite some time to make sense of it.

Comment: What is the purpose of the double dash following #Students? I noticed that the double single quotes in @myInput become single quote in the second print statement. can you explain why ? Thanks

Comment: I think I figured out the answers to my previous questions. And I feel quite dumb for even having to ask.  But hey, thanks.

Comment: hi @JohnSmithSr - sorry I didn't respond earlier to your 2nd comment above - I was away from my computer.    The double-dash indicates the remaining characters are simply a comment, and in the case of sql injection prevents characters after the double-dash from producing a syntax error.

Comment: The double single-quotes become a single quote when inside a quoted string due to convention.  The first single quote acts as an escape character for any immediately following single quote, when inside a string.  Compilers make intelligent guesses to infer when a set of characters is code vs data; in SQL Server single quotes denote the start and end of character-based data.  In order to allow character-based data to contain single quotes, a convention was required to allow the compiler to differentiate embedded quotes from string-ending quotes.